# how to remove text after "localhost" in browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am new in MVC. I have tested my site in debug mode. So far there is no problem. But when i deploy it to my localhost i am having an issues "POST http://localhost/Home/GetEnumerationList 404 (Not Found)". It looks like it failed to call the action in controller. When i look at the address it shows like this "http://localhost/mymvcsite" instead of like this "http://localhost". I have also test using Postman, when i run post as this "http://localhost/mymvcsite/Home/GetEnumerationList" only then i will get the result.

Is there a way i can set up my iis to remove "mymvcsite" from "http://localhost/mymvcsite"?

Here is the JQuery to call the Action in Controller.

```
<script>
    var popup, dataTable;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $("#batchTable").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/GetEnumerationList",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },

            "columns": [
                { "data": "EnumType", "name":"EnumType" },
                { "data": "EnumValue", "name": "EnumValue"  },
                { "data": "EnumText", "name": "EnumText"  },
                { "data": "IsDeleted", "name": "IsDeleted" },
                {
                    "data": "EnumId", "render": function (data) {
                        return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Home")/" + data +"')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'  style='margin-left: 5px' onclick=Delete(" + data +")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
                    },
                    "orderable": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "width": "150px"
                },

            ],

            "processing": "true",
            "serverSide": "true",
            "order": [0, "asc"]
        });
    });

    function PopupForm(url) {
        var formDiv = $('<div/>');

        $.get(url)
            .done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);



                popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: "Add Enum",
                    height: 470,
                    width: 300,
                    close: function () {
                        popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }
                });
            });
    }

    function SubmitForm(form) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

        if ($(form).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        popup.dialog('close');
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();

                        $.notify(data.message, {
                            globalPosition: "top center",
                            className: "success"
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }

    function Delete(id) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this data?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteEnum", "Home")/' + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                        $.notify(data.message, {
                            globalPosition: "top center",
                            className: "success"
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            )
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hopefully someone can please guide me on this.

Comment: this has something to do with your controller's url configuration. search for "mymvcsite" in your code to find out where it is defined.

Comment: Does your controller is in Area?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the default route mapped to your `mymvcsite` at your backend.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "mymvcsite", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of add the site as virtual directory of "Default Web Site", i add new website and point it to my webroot physical path. I hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: actually, it will be better that you add the solution code/config here for clarity.